# Proving "Or Statements" in Type Theory

Tags: constructive-mathematics, type-theory

Oftentimes in math we see statements of the form $P \to (Q \vee R)$.  To prove them we can assume $P$ is true and $R$ is false, and then demonstrate that $Q$ is true.  This method of proof has the form:
$$
[ (P \wedge \neg R) \to Q ] \to [ P \to ( Q \vee R ) ].
$$
It seems to me this would be valid in a constructive type theory.  I would have a function type, $H$, that takes $(p,f):P \wedge \neg R$ and gives $H(p,f):Q$.  To prove the above proof method, I would have to obtain from such a function another function, $g$, such that $g(p):Q \vee R$ when $p:P$.  This seems impossible, since the data that $H$ requires is both $p:P$ and $f:\neg R$.

Is this form of argument not valid in constructive type theory?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For intuitionistic logic, a proposition is a tautology iff it is identically true in the logic of open sets in the plane. (similar to how, in classical logic, it's valid iff its truth table in two-valued logic is identically true)

In this logic,

- $\top$ (or "true") is the whole plane
- $\bot$ (or "false") is the empty set
- $\vee$ is union
- $\wedge$ is intersection
- $\neg$ is exterior (not *complement*)
- $X \to Y$ is the interior of $X^c \cup Y$ ($X^c$ being the complement)

And we can construct a counterexample:

- Let $P$ be the whole plane
- Let $R$ be the whole plane minus the origin
- Let $Q \subseteq R$.

Then,

$$\begin{align}
[ (P \wedge \neg R) \to Q ] \to [ P \to ( Q \vee R ) ]
&= [ (\mathbb{R}^2 \cap \varnothing) \to Q ] 
\to [ \mathbb{R}^2 \to R ]
\\&= [\varnothing \to Q] \to R
\\&= \mathbb{R}^2 \to R
\\&= R
\end{align}$$

but $R \neq \mathbb{R}^2$, so this proposition is *not* a tautology in intuitionistic logic. (or in any system weaker than intuitionistic logic)

Comment: Thanks.  That's a handy tool to have in my toolbox.