# How Would an Intuitionist Prove This?

Tags: constructive-mathematics, intuitionistic-logic

I asked a question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1937550/proving-or-statements-in-type-theory) about whether
$$
[ (P \wedge \neg R) \to Q ] \to [ P \to (Q \vee R) ]
$$
is a tautology in intuitionistic math.  The answer is "no".  What prompted my question was my proof of the following: Let $a,b,n \in \mathbb{N}$.  If $n \neq 1$ and $n$ divides both $a$ and $b$, then $b$ is a composite number or $b$ divides $a$.  My proof:

Suppose $b$ is not composite.  Then $b$ is prime.  Since $n \neq 1$ and $n$ divides $b$, we must have $n = b$.  Thus $b$ divides $a$.

This proof has the form $(P \wedge \neg R) \to Q$.  If we were using normal first order logic, I could conclude $P \to (Q \vee R)$.  But, using intuitionistic logic, I cannot conclude that which was to be proven.  How would you carry out this proof in intuitionistic logic?

Comment: $[ (P \wedge \neg R) \to Q ]$ in your case is false in Peano Arithmetic with regard to being composite or b dividing a. However you by asserting that $[ (P \wedge \neg R) \to Q ]$ with regard to your case, you are considering a subset of possibilities within all possible solutions in PA. If you willing to assert that, then $[ P \to (P \vee Q) ]$ also holds within PA.

Comment: @user2277550 I have some questions.  Is $(P \wedge \neg R) \to Q$ not true because not being composite is not the same as being prime?  And I don't understand what you mean in your last two sentences.  Could you elaborate in an answer so I can give you credit?

Comment: Is there a typo in the question?  $[P\to(P\lor Q)]$ is intuitionistically valid, so the antecedent $[(P\land\neg R)\to Q]$ is irrelevant and the whole formula is intuitionisitically valid.

Comment: @AndreasBlass Typo.  It should read $P \to (Q \vee R)$.  Thanks for pointing it out.  It has been fixed.